# jQuery .load not loading URL with funny characters

Tags: jquery

Have got a PHP file with the following line of code:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
```

The HTML to contain the URL I'm trying to load is:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

The script I'm using is:

```
$(function(){
var contentURI= 'http://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#&destination=London%20%28and%20vicinity%29,%20England,%20United%20Kingdom&startDate=01/15/2015&endDate=01/16/2015&regionId=178279&adults=2';    // URL TO GRAB + # of any desired element // if needed :)
$('#result').load('grabber.php?url='+ contentURI);
});
```

What I'm trying to do is pull in hotels with a certain date range/location from Expedia - problem is the page loads fine but the hotel results aren't there...

What have I done wrong?

Comment: it's probably that expedia's site has other javascript on it that loads the results asynchronously. when you load the content from there, it's probably blocking those scripts from loading.

Comment: Hash part of URL cannot be send to the server

Answer (score 0):

Their page uses AJAX to load the hotels individually so you can't just fetch the full page like that.

The only thing you can to is to "hijack" their API calls and recreate the data on your page. That would be very hard and annoying to do (see the link below), and could break any day they decide to change something in their API or they decide to block cross-domain access.

See the data format they're using: http://www.expedia.com/ws/HotelSearchWebService/v1/opaqueDealsRequest?destinationName=London+(and+vicinity)&startDate=01%2F15%2F2015&endDate=01%2F16%2F2015&response=json

And that's just one of a few they're using.

Comment: Great, a downvote... can't wait to hear. Anything to add, Mr. @securedeveloper...

Comment: Just wondering, i don't get the joke, Who is Mr. @securedeveloper? Anyway +1 -1 = 0 ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff Hehe, he just deleted his answer which I downvoted so he's on a little revenge tour. See below. Thanks for the equilibrium! :)